# Ubicación de un fichero javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, asp.net

Cuando ubico el código javascript en un archivo aparte y lo mando a llamar con una instancia común no obtengo ningún resultado satisfactorio, al contrario si incrusto el código debajo del div tag que en el cual lo quiero ocupar, éste me funciona bien.

Hay algo que tenga que configurar en el web.config para que funcione solo escribiendo el vínculo?

Nota: Trabajo con ASP.NET y se trata de un web.config

Aquí mi código funcional (dentro del un body form . . . /form /body).

```
<div class="tab-pane-y3 scroll">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table" style="font-size:130%; font-family:Tahoma;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">
            <button id="btnRuta1" runat="server" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
              <span>Canal Detalle</span>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-right thAzul" colspan="3">Evolución</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th class="thAzul" colspan=3>Detalle</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="thAzul" rowspan=2>Cj. Vendidas</td>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lbDetalleCanal" runat="server" Text="0.00"></asp:Label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lbDetalleEvo" runat="server" Text="0.00"></asp:Label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lbDetalleCanal_p" runat="server" Text="0.00"></asp:Label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lbDetalleEvo_p" runat="server" Text="0.00"></asp:Label>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table" style="font-size:130%; font-family:Tahoma;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">
            <button id="btnRuta2" runat="server" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
              <span>Canal Mayorista</span>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>

          <th class="text-right thAzul" colspan="3">Evolución</th>
        </tr>


        <tr>
          <td class="thAzul" rowspan=2>Cj. Vendidas</td>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lbMayorCanal" runat="server" Text="0.00"></asp:Label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lbMayorEvo" runat="server" Text="0.00"></asp:Label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lbMayorCanal_p" runat="server" Text="0.00"></asp:Label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lbMayorEvo_p" runat="server" Text="0.00"></asp:Label>
          </td>
        </tr>


      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table" style="font-size:130%; font-family:Tahoma;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">
            <button id="btnRuta3" runat="server" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
              <span>Canal Supermercado</span>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </thead>
      <tbody>

        <tr>

          <th class="text-right thAzul" colspan="3">Evolución</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="thAzul" rowspan=2>Cj. Vendidas</td>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lbSuperCanal" runat="server" Text="0.00"></asp:Label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lbSuperEvo" runat="server" Text="0.00"></asp:Label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lbSuperCanal_p" runat="server" Text="0.00"></asp:Label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lbSuperEvo_p" runat="server" Text="0.00"></asp:Label>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>



</div>
<%--***** JS Webmethod ******--%>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

      $("[id*='_btnCheck']").click(function() {
        var buttonName = $(this).attr('id');
        ChannelEvent(buttonName);
      });

    });

    function ChannelEvent(buttonName) {


      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "inicio.aspx/CanalFunc",

        data: '{name: "' + buttonName + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function(response) {
          alert(response.d);
        }
      });
    }

    function OnSuccess(response) {

      document.getElementById('<%=lbDetalleCanal.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[0];
      document.getElementById('<%=lbDetalleEvo.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[1];
      document.getElementById('<%=lbDetalleCanal_p.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[2];
      document.getElementById('<%=lbDetalleEvo_p.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[3];

      document.getElementById('<%=lbMayorCanal.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[4];
      document.getElementById('<%=lbMayorEvo.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[5];
      document.getElementById('<%=lbMayorCanal_p.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[6];
      document.getElementById('<%=lbMayorEvo_p.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[7];

      document.getElementById('<%=lbSuperCanal.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[8];
      document.getElementById('<%=lbSuperEvo.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[9];
      document.getElementById('<%=lbSuperCanal_p.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[10];
      document.getElementById('<%=lbSuperEvo_p.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[11];

    }
  </script>
```

Si en vez del script pongo :

`"script src="js/webmethodChannels.js" type="text/javascript"`

Siempre abajo del tag, No me funciona el script. No sé que puede ser, me incomoda tenerlo ahí, xq si... necesito poner más scripts mas largos y no quiero llenar mi webpage de todo este código.

También lo puse abajo de la página, antes de que termine el form y el body y no funciona.

Comment: Si utilizas la ruta js/webmethodChannels.js el navegador va a realizar una petición del archivo webmethodChannels.js en la carpeta js que se encuentra dentro de la carpeta donde se encuentra la página.

Si la carpeta js está en el raíz del sitio web deberías utilizar "/js/webmethodChannels.js". Al comenzar con / la url relativa indicas que la ruta debe crearse a partir de la raíz del sitio web.

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que tendrias que hacer es validar si el .js se esta cargando con la pagina, para esto usa el `Developer Tool` del browser al cual accedes con F12, con la solapa `NetWork` podras validar si resuelve correctamente.

Entonces podrias definir una ruta fija desde el root del sitio web usando `ResolveClientUrl()`

```
<script src="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/js/webmethodChannels.js")%>" type="text/javascript" />
```

Esto se me habia presentado cuando usas masterpage

[[ASP.NET] Master Page - Referencia relativa a elemento](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2012/09/aspnet-master-page-referencia-relativa.html)

no se si es este tu caso, pero si el resolver la url relativa depende de quien lo contiene entonces aplicaria

Comment: debuggiando con el chrome, Si funciona el script , por creo que he descuidado de ellos. Creo que el principal problema es: document.getElementById('lbAno_a').innerHTML  no me lo ejecuta.

Comment: si usas el developer tools de los otros browser no resuelve el .js? a que url quiere buscarlo. Una cosa es que no carga un .js y una muy distinta es la seleccion de un elemento, en la Consola del developer tools que error puedes observar